# How can I use regular asp.net identity with a Blazor App?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I currently have an asp.net mvc 5 application, in one solution, spread out among six projects.  All six use the same asp.net identity (NOT .net core) authorization system.  I would like to add a seventh, server side Blazor project, but still use the original asp.net identity (NOT .net core) authorization system.

Essentially if the user logs in once there should be access to all 7 sites, and the same authorization cookie would work for all sites.  The original sites would be **on premises**, and the Blazor site would be on Azure.  All sites would share the same domain, but be on different subdomains.

Does anyone know if that is possible?  Essentially I just want to use the same auth cookie across on-premises and azure sites, with a .net core Blazor site as well as an MVC 5 site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Azure AD B2C.

This way your authorization is completely decoupled from your application. You can also mix up many different ways of authorization with the same user basis.

I don't exactly know how your current structure looks like, but if you are accessing the same database from different applications this may be pretty dangerous in terms of database concurrency.

Some useful resources on how to get started on Azure AD B2C are:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqfsKtoLHMQ
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview